# Evans PDE Chapter 5 Problem 11: Does $Du=0$ a.e. implie $u=c$ a.e.?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $W^{1,p}(U)$ be the Sobolev space. Suppose that $U$ is connected bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$ satisfies $Du=0$ a.e. in $U$. How can I prove that $u$ is constant a.e. in $U$?

Answer (score 4):

For a Dirac-family $(\varphi_\varepsilon)_\varepsilon$ with $\mathrm{supp}\, \varphi_\varepsilon \subseteq \overline{B_\varepsilon(0)}$ you have $D(u*\varphi_\varepsilon) = (Du)*\varphi_\varepsilon = 0$ on all open sets $O \subseteq U$ with $\mathrm{dist}(O,\partial U) > \delta$, with $\delta > \varepsilon$, so $u * \varphi_\varepsilon$ is constant on all connected ones. Also, $u*\varphi_\varepsilon \to u$ in $L^p$ for $p \geq 1$, in particular $u * \varphi_\varepsilon \to u$ almost everywhere for some subsequence. But this means $u$ is constant almost everywhere on all $O$ with $\mathrm{dist}(O,\partial U) > 0$, so it is constant almost everywhere on $U$.

Comment: Where do you use connectedness of $U$?

Comment: The $O$'s should be connected too, so $D(u*\varphi)=0$ there implies $u*\varphi$ constant.

Comment: It is intuitively quite true. Do you have a brief topological argument that why each $O$ is connected also?

Comment: I clarified my answer above. The first equality holds for all $O$, but the function is only constant on connected ones.

Comment: why $u\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}\to u$ in $L^{\infty}$?

Comment: However, we can avoid the question by choosing $\varepsilon $ as a countable series tends to $0$.