# Weak derivative zero implies constant function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

Let $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$ such that $Du=0$ a.e. on $U$. I have to prove that $u$ is constant a.e. on $U$.

Take $(\rho_{\varepsilon})_{\varepsilon>0}$ mollifiers. I know that $D(u\ast\rho_{\varepsilon})=Du\ast\rho_{\varepsilon}$, so $u\ast\rho_{\varepsilon}(x)=c $ for every $x\in U$, since it is a smooth function.

How can I conclude?

Comment: Actually, $c=c_\varepsilon$. Now show that this has a convergent subsequence as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$

Comment: How can I prove that $c=c_{\varepsilon}$?

Comment: Your $c$ depends on $\varepsilon$ by definition.

Comment: I don't understand how to proceed

Answer (score 9):

By (well-known) properties of mollification, $u*\rho_\epsilon\rightarrow u$ in $W^{1,p}$ as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. Since $u*\rho_\epsilon = c_\varepsilon$ is a constant for each $\varepsilon$, and  $u*\rho_\epsilon\rightarrow u$, $u$ is the limit of constant functions and must be constant as well (e.g. because convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence a.e.).

you should note that

i) this is only true for each connected component of $U$

ii) strictly speaking $u*\rho_\epsilon$ is only defined on $U_\varepsilon = \{x\in U: d(x,\mathbb{R}^n\backslash U)>\varepsilon\}$, so you first get the result for any such domain, but then it it true for $U$ if $\varepsilon$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Is the limit of constant functions always constant? (if it exists)

Comment: @avati91 'Limit' always refers to a definition of convergence or a topology, e.g. pointwise convergence or convergence in some norm. The answer to your question depends on the notion of convergence which is used, but in most cases the answer would be yes (again, on each component of the domain of definition).

Comment: @avati91, yes, the weak limit of constant functions here is constant. Take a decreasing sequence $\epsilon_n$ that tends to zero. We know that $u\ast \rho_{\epsilon_n}$ converges to $u$ in $L^p_{\text{loc}}(U)$. But unless the numbers $c_{\epsilon_n}$ form a convergent sequence, this $L^p_{\text{loc}}(U)$ convergence cannot happen. Therefore, the constants $c_{\epsilon_n}$ must converge as numbers. Then it is easy to see that the limit of  $u\ast \rho_{\epsilon_n}$ in $L^p_{\text{loc}}(U)$ is $\lim_n c_{\epsilon_n}$.

Comment: Does "convergence in Lp implies convergence a.e" hold in general?  In mollification case $u\ast \rho_\varepsilon \to u$ a.e. holds indeed 
 (c.f. Theorem 9.13 and Theorem 7.15 in Zygmund's book, Measure and Integral for $L^1$ case and this(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096491/almost-everywhere-convergence-of-convolution-with-mollifiers#comment2234778_1096491) for $L^p$ case )

Comment: @user74489 See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere

Comment: Yes, I knew Davide Giraudo's answer in your link. But now I am in addition  interested about whether $u\star \rho_\varepsilon \to u$ as $\varepsilon\searrow 0$ almost everywhere, and finding some resource.

Comment: I just wanted to comment about a delicate point regarding connectedness in your argument. (I think it might help future readers). The point is that $u \star \rho_{\epsilon}$ is only constant on $U_{\epsilon}$ if we know $U_{\epsilon}$ is connected. This is not always the case, even for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ (think of a sequence of "forks" with bases which become thinner and thinner). Thus a more local argument  is needed, like the one in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/349027/104576). This shows $u$ is locally a.e constant...,

Comment: and now a gluing argument is needed (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948128/can-locally-a-e-constant-function-on-a-connected-subset-u-of-mathbbrn)) in order to finish the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $u, \text{weak } u' \in L^p_{loc}(U)$ (this is the general definition of $W^{1,p}(U))$. By $u'=0$ a.e., we know after mollification, $u_{\epsilon}' = C_{\epsilon}$ a.e. in $\Omega_{\epsilon}$. Since $u_{\epsilon} \to u$ in $L^p_{loc}$, then for any compact subset $W$ of $\Omega$, we know the $L^p$ convergence on $W$. Hence $C_{\epsilon} \to u$ on any compact subset. This immediately shows that $C_{\epsilon}$ is a bounded sequence and by Bolzano-Weierstrass, $C_\epsilon$ admits a convergent subsequence. Fix this convergent subsequence, and WLOG assume $C_{\epsilon} \to C$ as a sequence of real number. On $W$, $\vert\vert u-C \vert\vert_p \leq \vert\vert u-C_\epsilon \vert\vert_p + \vert\vert C_\epsilon - C\vert\vert_p$, the right hand side tends to $0$ by $L^p_{loc}$ convergence of $u_{\epsilon}$ and $W$ being of finite measure. Then $u=C$ a.e. on $W$. If here we assume $U$ is a bounded open domain, then by $\bar{\Omega}_\epsilon$  compact in $U$ and increasing to $U$, we can conclude the result by taking $\epsilon \to 0$.