# Almost everywhere convergence of convolution with mollifiers

Tags: integration, lp-spaces, convolution

I read that for $j\in L^1({\mathbb R}^n)$ with $\|j\|_1=1$ and $f\in L^1_{\rm loc}({\mathbb R}^n)$ the mollifiers $j_\epsilon(x):=\epsilon^{-n}j(x/\epsilon)$ exhibit $j_\epsilon\ast f\in L^1({\mathbb R}^n)$ and $j_\epsilon\ast f\rightarrow f$ in $L^1({\mathbb R}^n)$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.  But convergence in $L^1({\mathbb R}^n)$ does not imply convergence almost everywhere, yet I couldn't find a counterexample for this case, so do we additionally have $j_\epsilon\ast f\rightarrow f$ pointwise almost everywhere or not?

Comment: What is $F^1$? Also, I think we need $\|j,L^1\|=1$. Also, if $j$ is regular, then the convolution also has some regularity. If you want to biuld some counterexamples, take $j$ very irregular.

Comment: Sorry, $F^1=L^1$, edited!

Comment: [Here](http://nzjm.math.auckland.ac.nz/images/d/d5/Convergence_of_sequences_of_convolution_operators.pdf) is some work related to this, the question seems trickier than I anticipated.

Comment: If that article completely answers your question, I suggest posting that link as an answer and outline the major results form the article; like this people will see what is going on (even if the article is removed from that site or their server is down).

Comment: It's not answering it completely but I'll still post it as an answer because it gives some interesting related theorems.  I just have to work through it first...