# Derivative of mollification

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, convolution

This is in response to a claim made in the second line of the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958969), namely:

Given the standard mollifier $\eta$ and a locally integrable function $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, by defining the mollification of $f^{\epsilon}$ in the usual way ($f^{\epsilon}:=f*\eta_{\epsilon}$), (where $\eta_{\epsilon}:=\epsilon^{-n}\eta(x/\epsilon))$, if $f\in W^{1,p}(U)$ then $D(f^{\epsilon}) = Df * \eta_{\epsilon}$.

(Where $Df$ is, of course, the weak derivative of $f$.)

I can show this works for the other side (i.e. that  $D(f^{\epsilon}) = f * D(\eta_{\epsilon})$), but don't know how to incorporate the definition of the weak derivative to show the claim. Does anyone know a nice proof?

Comment: $\partial^\alpha(u*v)=(\partial^\alpha u)*v$ is true for all Schwartz *distributions* such that one of them has compact support.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without referring to distributions?

Comment: If you shrink the set $U$ suitably, this is true, I.e. your equality holds on $U_\epsilon =\{x \mid dist(x,U^c)>\epsilon\}$. I don't think (at least I never saw the claim) that this also holds on all of $U$.

Comment: You have correctly deduced that $D(f^{\epsilon})(x)=\int f(y)D(\eta_{\epsilon})(x-y)dy$. How are you having trouble applying the definition of the weak derivative to this integral expression?

Comment: Never mind, I see the answer to my question is in Evans.

Comment: This is why I hate this website.

Comment: It's on page 250, for future readers of this thread. Basically the idea is that $$\int f(y) D_x \eta(x-y) dy = - \int f(y) D_y \eta(x-y) dy $$ and then applying the definition.