# Evans PDE: $Du =0$ a.e. implies that $u$ is a constant a.e.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

I am aware that this question has been [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/348593/258202) on Math SE. I'm curious why my proposed solution was marked incorrect by the grader in my partial differential equations course.

---

Original question in Chapter $5$ of Evans (Exercise $5.10.11$)

> Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with a smooth boundary $\partial U$. Suppose $U$ is connected and $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$ satisfies
> $$Du=0 \quad \text{a.e. in $U$}.$$
> Prove $u$ is constant a.e. in $U$.

---

Proposed solution:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then consider the smooth functions
$$u_{\varepsilon}= \eta_{\varepsilon}\ast u \in C^{\infty}(U_{\varepsilon}),$$
where $U_{\varepsilon}=\{x\in U: d(x,\partial U) > \varepsilon\}$. By Theorem 5.3.1 in Evans, we have
$$D_{x_i}(u_{\varepsilon})=\eta_{\varepsilon}\ast D_{x_i}u.$$
Therefore, by assumption, $D_{x_i}u_{\varepsilon}=0$ a.e. in $U_{\varepsilon}$. So $u_{\varepsilon}$ is constant on each connected subset of $U_{\varepsilon}$.

Next, let $x,y\in U$. Since $U$ is connected, there exists a polygonal path $\Gamma\subseteq U$ which connects $x$ and $y$.

[image]
Figure $1$: If $U$ is connected then its subdomain $U_{\varepsilon}$ may not be connected. However, any two points $x,y\in U$ can be connected by a polygonal path $\Gamma$ remaining inside $U$. So, if $\varepsilon >0$ is sufficiently small, then $x$ and $y$ belong to the same connected component of $U_{\varepsilon}$.

Let $\delta=\underset{z\in\Gamma}{\min} ~d(z,\partial U)$ be the minimum distance of points in $\Gamma$ to the boundary of $U$. Then for every $\varepsilon < \delta$ the whole polygonal  curve $\Gamma$  is  in  $U_{\varepsilon}$. So $x,y$ lie  in  the  same connected  component  of  $U_{\varepsilon}$. Hence $u_{\varepsilon}(x)=u_{\varepsilon}(y)\equiv \text{const}.$

As $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$, Theorem 7 in Appendix C of Evans tells us that
$$u_{\varepsilon}\overset{\varepsilon \to0}{\longrightarrow } u ~\text{a.e. in $U$}.$$

Thus, $u$ is a constant a.e. in $U$.

---

The grader marked my answer as incorrect because connected does not imply path connected. While this is certainly true, I don't think that it destroys the analysis in this context.

Is this analysis incorrect? Could you fix the analysis by a similar argument?

Comment: If by domain is meant an open connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then connectedness $\iff$ path-connectedness, so you're right.

Comment: @Chrystomath: Yes, Evans states that the domain is open and connected in $\mathbb R^n$ which implies path-connectedness. I don't see anything wrong with the analysis - which is why I made a new question on Math SE.

Comment: I understand that the equivalence is used there: A set is connected if and only if it is polygonally connected.

Well, we already know that connected does not imply connected by paths.

Comment: @Mathstudy: The assumptions given in the problem are that $U$ is an open, connected subset of $\mathbb R^n$. This is (by default) path connected. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766422/when-does-open-and-connected-imply-path-connected.

Comment: @Axion004 Thank you, your citation has been helpful, since I did not remember this result. I thank you for recommending a book in which this result has been demonstrated.